# How to create a table in rails by running a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have created a migration file for creating a table UserDetails in my db.. and it was working fine b4...

Unknowingly I deleted that table to do some modification .. But now when i gave

rake db:migrate .. its not creating the table ..

I have the migration file .. BUt when i give rake db:migrate its not creating.. How to do so ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails maintains a 'schema_migrations' table to know what migrations have already run and will not run the migrations that have already been completed. Since, you had already run the migration once, it would have updated the 'schema_migrations' table with the version no. of the migration. You can do rake `db:rollback` to revert the last migration run or rake `db:migrate:down VERSION=<version_number>` to revert any migration that was run before.

Now, I suggest if you know the version no (Time stamp of the file), you can manually delete from 'schema_migrations' table and re-run `db:migrate`.

Comment: i just deleted the migration and generated a new migration and run it.. this is all in my local machine..

Comment: See now i have 2 migrations files added in my db/migrate one for creating UserDetails and Usertags table.. If i am pushing these things to master how others will get these migrations.. Will by simply running rake db:migrate in their machine after pulling the latest code will work ??

Answer (score 0):

Rake stores the time of the most recent migration inside the database - if the migration you're trying to run is older than that, it won't run with `rake db:migrate`.

I don't know how to run a specific migration manually, sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

Could you just run that specific migration as stated in the Guides. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#being-specific

I have run specific migrations by their timestamp before. It seems like it would work in this situation also.